# What happens when a session expires?

Tags: c#, asp.net

What does asp.net do in the background when a session expires?  Is the session completely disposed of, or do I need to add something like `Session.Abandon();` in my `Session_End` event in Global.asax?

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by "disposed of"? Are you asking whether `IDisposable.Dispose` is called on all objects in the session?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In-memory state - the object is removed from list of sessions and `Session_End` is called. For SQL session state nothing happens and data will no longer be returned for future requests with the same session ID since it does not match (ID + non-expired) condition.

You don't need to call `Session.Abandon()` in `Session_End` because that event called when session is expired (which is exactly what  `Abandon` does).

Notes

- normal web applications that use out-of-process session state (SQL on state service) will not receive `Session_End` event because out-ouf-process state does not fire it.
- if you need to cleanup SQL session state you can run clenaup task that deletes rows for expired sessions.

Answer (score 1):

The session is completely disposed. You don't need to do anything special. `Session_End` is an event that allows you to do things upon session disposal.

`Session.Abandon()` is a command that lets you terminate a session at will.

Note: If you don't put any variable in the `Session`, then `Session_End` will not fire.

Comment: Note that this answer explicitly talks about in-proc session state.

Comment: @Ofer Zelig, Hi Ofer, I know it's been a long time since you offered this solution and I would like to ask your clarification. So, when session expires it means all my preferences will be gone, for example, language preference and after expiration I will have to reselect the language again. I know this might a wierd question and you can say it is logical if session is gone then preferences as well. Since I am just beginner, I wonder maybe there are nuances. Another wierd question, look if cookie expires then will it mean the expiration of session as well since cookie and session are connected

Answer (score 1):

Session will get cleared if you were using inproc session provider so you won't need to call `Session.Abandon()`.